# Dealing with an ancient unsalvageable question which scored 0 points and had zero interest

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban

Please note this question is being asked by a user that is **banned** from asking questions, is trying to do something about, is not trying to dodge the results of previous questions.

I am wondering what to do with several ancient questions I asked more than 4 years ago, they score zero points, nobody commented on then. Computing technology has moved on since they were asked.

I can not see any reasonable way of salvaging them so I am wondering what is the best thing to do about it. Few people looked at the questions when they were originally asked. They are currently in the state of automatic deletion.

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089196/stylting-a-wfs-polygon-in-openlayers3) Was asked 5 years ago, the library used has moved on 2 issues since then.
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449216/porting-from-jboss5-to-jboss7-list-of-references) Was asked 4 years ago and refers to Jboss 5.

Comment: I fully understand that they have been deleted, can no longer be found by anybody else, but  I have been advised that they still count towards a ban and trying to salvage  them may help.  I am not asking for a 'get out of jail free' card, but advice as to what to do.

If the advice is that there is nothing that I can do about questions like these, then fair enough, I will know not to  waste either  communities or my time is trying to do something about

Comment: Nothing. Let them go. There are 30 other questions for you to focus that could impact your post-ban situation. These two should not be your priority.

Comment: Maybe there are **other** deleted questions that are better targets for improvement. Have you gotten a list of your deleted questions from a mod?

Comment: If there is nothing that can be done about them, I can cross that  particularly category of question of my todo list

Comment: I don't see what there is to salvage. While the precise rating rules are not known, merely deleting a neutral question should not have a negative impact. ["If a post was **poorly-received (downvoted or closed)**, that will continue to count against your account even if the post is deleted!".](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: @Dave Unless I'm missing something the system doesn't show you as being Q-banned.

Comment: Up until last week I was questioned banned,  I deliberately  waited 6 months to see what would happen.  Ever since I read some where else on stack overflow, that if you get question banned your allowed to post another one in 6 months, you will then be locked again while that question is judged by the community.

I was expecting some type of comment, mega warning feedback along the lines 'Warning your are allowed to ask a single question, make it a good one'  Instead nothing, its as if somebody is giving me just enough rope.
There is still the matter of those previous question to be resolved

Comment: @Dave  that kind of a warning sounds useful. Can you write a [tag:feature-request] for it here on meta?

Comment: @Yatin [Filed a feature request on the global meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361877/let-question-banned-users-know-that-theyre-banned-even-if-their-6-month-limit-h)